# Creating an illustrator script to output swatches and list them

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe-illustrator

You'll have to excuse me, I'm terrible when it comes to javascript.

I am working on an Illustrator script to create a booklet full of colours, I have this working ok, a bit messy at the moment but It works.

I now need to create extra pages with a list of those Pantone colours and what pages they are on.

For instance, the book starts on page 2 and will have 7 colours on it, it then goes to page 3 with a further 7 colours and so on till there's no colours left.

So what I need to do is edit the following script to say, after 7 items increase the page number by 1.

Here's part of the script:

```
main();
function main()
{
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var selectedSwatches = doc.swatches.getSelected();


if (selectedSwatches.length > 0)
{
    var text = 'var spots = new Array(\n';


    for (var i = 0; i < selectedSwatches.length; i++)
    {
        var swatch = selectedSwatches[i]
        var color = swatch.color;


        // Spot
        if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
          for(var j = 1; j < 8; j++){
            text += '"' + color.spot.name + "page" + i+ '", ' + "\n";
          }

            color = color.spot.color;
        }

    }
    var textend = ');';
    saveTxt(text + textend);
}
else {
    alert("No Swatches Selected.");
}
}


function saveTxt(txt)
{
var name = app.activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');
var path = (app.activeDocument.path != "") ? app.activeDocument.path : "~";


var saveFile = new File(path + "/" + name + "-SPOT.txt");


if(saveFile.exists)
    saveFile.remove();


saveFile.encoding = "UTF8";
saveFile.open("e", "TEXT");
saveFile.writeln(txt);
saveFile.close();


alert("Saved to File:\n" + saveFile.fullName)
}
```

This is the part that causing me issues I think:

```
// Spot
if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
  for(var j = 1; j < 8; j++){
    text += '"' + color.spot.name + "page" + i+ '", ' + "\n";
  }

  color = color.spot.color;
```

}

As it stands, first of all it starts at page 0, it should start at page 2.

It also output 7 lines for each colour, it should output 1 colour for each 7 lines.

I've attacged a screenshot of the output.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for your problem

```
main();

function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var selectedSwatches = doc.swatches.getSelected();
    var pageNumber = 2;
    var count = 0;
    if (selectedSwatches.length > 0) {
        var text = 'var spots = new Array(\n';
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedSwatches.length; i++) {
            var swatch = selectedSwatches[i]
            var color = swatch.color;
            // Spot
            if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
                count++;
                text += '"' + color.spot.name + " page" + pageNumber + '", ' + "\n";
                color = color.spot.color;
                if (count % 7 == 0)
                    pageNumber++;
            }

        }
        var textend = ');';
        saveTxt(text + textend);
    } else {
        alert("No Swatches Selected.");
    }
}


function saveTxt(txt) {
    var name = app.activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');
    var path = (app.activeDocument.path != "") ? app.activeDocument.path : "~";
    var saveFile = new File(path + "/" + name + "-SPOT.txt");
    if (saveFile.exists)
        saveFile.remove();
    saveFile.encoding = "UTF8";
    saveFile.open("e", "TEXT");
    saveFile.writeln(txt);
    saveFile.close();


    alert("Saved to File:\n" + saveFile.fullName)
}
```

This code will start with page number 2 and as soon as 7 different colors are displayed on page 2 it will move to page 3 to display another 7 colors. Hope my answer will help you. Enjoy.. :)